# LNK2019 error with Eclipse Paho MQTT C for a Visual Studio C++ project (win64)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mqtt, paho

I want to use the Eclipse Paho MQTT C library in a simple C++ program. For the library i used the the pre-build binaries for windows - see https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.paho/downloads

- C client for Windows 1.3.0 - 64 bit

I found the exact same issue in this talk [LNK2019 error when compiling a Visual C++ Win32 project with Eclipse Paho MQTT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27999199/lnk2019-error-when-compiling-a-visual-c-win32-project-with-eclipse-paho-mqtt).

For linkage in include I have the following setting:

- C/C++ - Additional include: xxx\paho\eclipse-paho-mqtt-c-win64-1.3.0\include
- Linker - additional Additional Library Directories
- Linker - input - additional dependencies:
- eclipse-paho-mqtt-c-win64-1.3.0\lib\paho-mqtt3cs.lib
- eclipse-paho-mqtt-c-win64-1.3.0\lib\paho-mqtt3c.lib
- eclipse-paho-mqtt-c-win64-1.3.0\lib\paho-mqtt3a.lib
- eclipse-paho-mqtt-c-win64-1.3.0\lib\paho-mqtt3as.lib

My code is as follows:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

extern "C" {
#include <MQTTClient.h>
#include <MQTTClientPersistence.h>
}
#define ADDRESS     "xxx"
#define CLIENTID    "ExampleClientSub"
#define TOPIC       "xxx"
#define PAYLOAD     "Hello World!"
#define QOS         1
#define TIMEOUT     10000L

int main()
{
MQTTClient client;
MQTTClient_connectOptions conn_opts = MQTTClient_connectOptions_initializer;
int rc;
int ch;

MQTTClient_create(&client, ADDRESS, CLIENTID,
    MQTTCLIENT_PERSISTENCE_NONE, NULL);
conn_opts.keepAliveInterval = 20;
conn_opts.cleansession = 1;
conn_opts.username = "roman.busse";
conn_opts.password = "VojUriLKhOsmzUJQ1lld";

MQTTClient_setCallbacks(client, NULL, connlost, msgarrvd, delivered);

if ((rc = MQTTClient_connect(client, &conn_opts)) != MQTTCLIENT_SUCCESS)
{
    printf("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
printf("Subscribing to topic %s\nfor client %s using QoS%d\n\n"
    "Press Q<Enter> to quit\n\n", TOPIC, CLIENTID, QOS);
MQTTClient_subscribe(client, TOPIC, QOS);

do
{
    ch = getchar();
} while (ch != 'Q' && ch != 'q');

MQTTClient_unsubscribe(client, TOPIC);
MQTTClient_disconnect(client, 10000);
MQTTClient_destroy(&client);

return 0;
}
```

So like you can see i said to the compiler: "Yes this is a C lib". But all in all I get the same LNK2019 errors...

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _MQTTClient_setCallbacks
>   referenced in function
>   _main paho_test   C:\Users\rtreiber\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\paho_test\paho_test\paho_test.obj   1
>   Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _MQTTClient_create referenced
>   in function _main paho_test   C:\Users\rtreiber\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\paho_test\paho_test\paho_test.obj   1
>   Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _MQTTClient_connect
>   referenced in function
>   _main paho_test   C:\Users\rtreiber\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\paho_test\paho_test\paho_test.obj   1
>   Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _MQTTClient_disconnect
>   referenced in function
>   _main paho_test   C:\Users\rtreiber\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\paho_test\paho_test\paho_test.obj   1
>   Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _MQTTClient_subscribe
>   referenced in function
>   _main paho_test   C:\Users\rtreiber\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\paho_test\paho_test\paho_test.obj   1
>   Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _MQTTClient_unsubscribe
>   referenced in function
>   _main paho_test   C:\Users\rtreiber\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\paho_test\paho_test\paho_test.obj   1
>   Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _MQTTClient_freeMessage
>   referenced in function "int __cdecl msgarrvd(void *,char *,int,struct
>   MQTTClient_message *)"
>   (?msgarrvd@@YAHPAXPADHPAUMQTTClient_message@@@Z)  paho_test   C:\Users\rtreiber\documents\visual
>   studio 2017\Projects\paho_test\paho_test\paho_test.obj    1
>   Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _MQTTClient_free referenced
>   in function "int __cdecl msgarrvd(void *,char *,int,struct
>   MQTTClient_message *)"
>   (?msgarrvd@@YAHPAXPADHPAUMQTTClient_message@@@Z)  paho_test   C:\Users\rtreiber\documents\visual
>   studio 2017\Projects\paho_test\paho_test\paho_test.obj    1
>   Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _MQTTClient_destroy
>   referenced in function
>   _main paho_test   C:\Users\rtreiber\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\paho_test\paho_test\paho_test.obj   1    Error  LNK1120 9
>   unresolved externals  paho_test   C:\Users\rtreiber\documents\visual
>   studio 2017\Projects\paho_test\Debug\paho_test.exe    1

So any ideas?

Comment: Please edit the question to include the full text of the errors

Comment: I edited the linker errrors, i looked up the library and it's every function imported with "DLLExport". I have the dll's within the folder with the static libs, and in the folder of the executable. I even tried it to add it as path variable-

Comment: New finding: If I use the 32bit binaries i can build the program but it can not be startet, because the program is running on a 64 bit system...